# GCloud showing wrong output for these two commands. What to do for it?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

When I run with parameter(--filter=-labels:*) it throws below error

```
gcloud dataproc clusters list --region='europe-west1' --filter=-labels:*
ERROR: (gcloud.dataproc.clusters.list) INTERNAL: Internal database error: Clusters in project 'arbitaryname'
```

For 2nd command, when I run this it shows all the resources with labels.

```
gcloud container clusters list --filter=-labels:*
```

Something is wrong. Does anybody knows any alternative to achieve. My ultimate goal is list resources without labels.

Answer (score 2):

To list the resources without labels you can do:

```
gcloud container clusters list --filter="labels.len():0"
```